# How to segue to a different view controller on the last page in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have two different view controllers. One is programmatically created(slideshow) and the other is with the interface builder(Login page). On the slideshow, once the user reaches the last page, it should perform segue to the login page.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can't create a segue between a VC created in code and another created in IB ( as both should be in IB ) , you must present it like this

```
let login = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginID") as! loginViewController
```

and use

```
self.present(login, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

OR use this to completely clear the stack of shown VCs

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = login
```

Comment: Sorry but I am still quite new to swift. Could you explain where I should put those codes and what should I do about my view controllers? Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

If two view controller don't need to transmit data, you can just change window root view controller to login page. Of course, with animation would be better.